# What is the use of 'abstract override' in C#?

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract

Just out of curiosity I tried overriding a abstract method in base class, and method the implementation abstract. As below:

```
public abstract class FirstAbstract
{
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public abstract class SecondAbstract : FirstAbstract
{
    public abstract override void SomeMethod();
    //?? what sense does this make? no implementaion would anyway force the derived classes to implement abstract method?
}
```

Curious to know why C# compiler allows writing 'abstract override'. Isn't it redundant? Should be a compile time error to do something like this. Does it serve to some use-case?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I've used this feature a couple times. There are definitely use cases.

Comment: this should help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/07/abstract-override.aspx

Comment: why should something that is merely redundant cause a compile time error?

Comment: @saus because some redundant things are silly enough that they suggest a mistake or misunderstanding and hence an error or at least a warning is appropriate. `public` on interface members would be an example.

Comment: I had a use case and was researching how to do this, which led me to this question. Your question answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There's a useful example for this on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members) - basically you can force a derived class to provide a new implementation for a method.

```
public class D
{
    public virtual void DoWork(int i)
    {
        // Original implementation.
    }
}

public abstract class E : D
{
    public abstract override void DoWork(int i);
}

public class F : E
{
    public override void DoWork(int i)
    {
        // New implementation.
    }
}
```

> If a virtual method is declared abstract, it is still virtual to any
>   class inheriting from the abstract class. **A class inheriting an
>   abstract method cannot access the original implementation of the
>   method**—in the previous example, DoWork on class F cannot call DoWork
>   on class D. **In this way, an abstract class can force derived classes
>   to provide new method implementations for virtual methods**.

Comment: What if I did something like `F ff = new F();  D dd = ff as D;  dd.DoWork(0);`?  Wouldn't that call `D`'s implementation? And if that's true, could I put inside `F`'s `DoWork(int i)`'s code something like `D dd = this as D;  dd.DoWork(i);`? Would that call `D`'s implementation?

Comment: @Blueriver as with any virtual member, it would call the implementation of the actual object, so it that case it would call `F`'s implementation.

Answer (score 57):

I find it really useful for ensuring proper `ToString()` implementation in derived classes. Let's say you have abstract base class, and you really want all derived classes to define meanigful `ToString()` implementation because you are actively using it. You can do it very elegantly with `abstract override`:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract override string ToString();
}
```

It is a clear signal to implementers that `ToString()` will be used in base class in some way (like writing output to user). Normally, they would not think about defining this override.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a great example that really belongs in this thread. Same example was also given in [an old answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1769064/1336654) on Stack Overflow, just for comparison.

Answer (score 16):

Interestingly enough, the Roslyn version of the C# compiler has an abstract override method in it, which I found odd enough to write an article about:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/07/strange-but-legal/

Comment: This makes sense if the base class’s member is `virtual`, but the compiler still allows it when the base member is `abstract`. Beyond guarding against the possibility that the base class’s member may one day be changed to be `virtual`, is that ever a valid pattern?

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that `SecondAbstract` is in the middle of a three-class hierarchy, and it wants to implement some abstract methods from its base `FirstAbstract` while leaving some other method X to be implemented from its child `ThirdAbstract`.

In this case, `SecondAbstract` is forced to decorate the method X with `abstract` since it does not want to provide an implementation; at the same time, it is forced to decorate it with `override` since it is not defining a new method X, but wants to move the responsibility of implementing X to its child. Hence, `abstract override`.

In general, the concepts modelled by `abstract` and `override` are orthogonal. The first forces derived classes to implement a method, while the second recognizes that a method is the same as specified on a base class and not a `new` one.

Therefore:

- neither keyword: "simple" method
- `abstract` only: derived class must implement
- `override` only: implementation of method defined in base class
- `abstract override`: derived class must implement a method defined in base class

Comment: But SecondAbstract is not required to include method X at all, since SecondAbstract is an abstract class. Adding X and decorating it as abstract override is equivalent to not including X at all, which is what the OP meant by redundant I guess.

Comment: Does it mean that `SecondAbstract` is not satisfied with method X implementation of the base class?

Answer (score 0):

This is done because in child class you can not have `abstract` method with same name as in base class. `override` tells compiler that you are overriding the behavior of base class.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not declare `SomeMethod` as `abstract override` in `SecondAbstract`, the compiler would expect that class to contain an implementation of the method. With `abstract override` it is clear that the implementation should be in a class derived from `SecondAbstract` and not in `SecondAbstract` itself.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This design pattern is known as the Template Method pattern.

[Wikipedia page on Template Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

A simple, non-software example:  There are a bunch of military units: tanks, jets, soldiers, battleships, etc.  They all need to implement some common methods but they will implement them very differently:

- Move()
- Attack()
- Retreat()
- Rest()

etc...