# Decorator pattern and C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I tried to run the following sample program in C# I get the output "You are getting a computer" instead of "You’re getting a computer and a disk and a monitor and a KeyBoard".

Why is this happens C# only not in Java.
I java the same code I get the appropriate output.

If I debug I found created  object hierarchy is correct but invoking computer.getComputer() always goes to Super class not in drived class, that is the problem.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
namespace DecoratorTest1
{

    public class Computer
    {
        public Computer()
        {
        }

        public  String getComputer()
        {
            return "computer";
        }
    }


    public abstract class ComponentDecorator : Computer
    {
        public abstract String getComputer();
    }

    public class Disk : ComponentDecorator
    {
        Computer computer;
        public Disk(Computer c)
        {
            computer = c;
        }


        public override String getComputer()
        {
            return computer.getComputer() + " and a disk";
        }

    }

    public class Monitor : ComponentDecorator
    {
        Computer computer;
        public Monitor(Computer c)
       {
            computer = c;
        }
        public override String getComputer()
        {
            return computer.getComputer() + " and a Monitor";
        }

    }

    public class KeyBoard : ComponentDecorator
    {
        Computer computer;
        public KeyBoard(Computer c)
       {
            computer = c;
        }

        public  override String getComputer()
        {
            return computer.getComputer() + " and a KeyBoard";
        }

        public string call()
        {
            return "";
        }

    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer = new Disk(computer);
            computer = new Monitor(computer);
            computer = new KeyBoard(computer);


            Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could remove `ComponentDecorator` and make the `getComputer` in `Computer` base class as `virtual`, so, you can have a default  behaviour and get it working fine in child classes.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Isn't that against the decorator pattern he's asking about? The whole idea is to not modify `Computer` because its probably not part of your code base.

Answer (score 13):

## Decorator in C#

When using the [decorator pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator), the idea is to have several classes implementing the same interface. One of them is the normal concrete implementation of the interface, `Computer` in your case. The others add something to the behavior of `Computer`. We can get rid of the `ComponentDecorator`. You can create an abstract decorator class that implements the `IComputer` interface, but you don't have to.

### Getting started

We start by creating the interface and making your concrete `Computer` implement it:

```
public interface IComputer
{
    string getComputer();
}

public sealed class Computer : IComputer
{
    public string getComputer()
    {
        return "computer";
    }
}
```

`Computer` here is `sealed`. It doesn't have to be, but is done in this case to show that decorators exist *next to* your concrete class, instead of *deriving from it*.

### Without abstract baseclass for decorators

The decorators implement `IComputer` instead of `ComponentDecorator`:

```
public class Disk : IComputer
{
    IComputer _computer;
    public Disk(IComputer computer)
    {
        _computer = computer;
    }

    public String getComputer()
    {
        return _computer.getComputer() + " and a disk";
    }
}

public class Monitor : IComputer
{
    IComputer _computer;
    public Monitor(IComputer computer)
    {
        _computer = computer;
    }

    public String getComputer()
    {
        return _computer.getComputer() + " and a Monitor";
    }
}

public class KeyBoard : IComputer
{
    IComputer _computer;
    public KeyBoard(IComputer computer)
    {
        _computer = computer;
    }

    public  String getComputer()
    {
        return _computer.getComputer() + " and a KeyBoard";
    }
}
```

### With abstract baseclass for decorators

If you do choose to use an abstract class to implement decorators, have it take an `IComputer` as dependency in the constructor. Furthermore, you should then use `base.getComputer()` instead of `computer.getComputer()`, like so:

```
public abstract class ComputerDecorator : IComputer
{
    private IComputer _computer;
    public ComputerDecorator(IComputer computer)
    {
        _computer = computer;
    }

    public virtual string getComputer()
    {
        return _computer.getComputer();
    }
}

public class Disk : ComputerDecorator
{
    public Disk(IComputer computer) : base(computer)
    {
    }

    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return base.getComputer() + " and a disk";
    }
}

public class Monitor : ComputerDecorator
{
    public Monitor(IComputer computer) : base(computer)
    {
    }

    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return base.getComputer() + " and a Monitor";
    }
}

public class KeyBoard : ComputerDecorator
{
    public KeyBoard(IComputer computer) : base(computer)
    {
    }

    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return base.getComputer() + " and a KeyBoard";
    }
}
```

In both cases, we can wrap it all up in the same way:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComputer computer = new KeyBoard(new Monitor(new Disk(new Computer())));

        Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
    }
}
```

See it work [with](http://ideone.com/dW9mQW) and [without](http://ideone.com/SYttYs) abstract decorator.

### What if we can't change the base class

User [InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767890/inbetween) suggested that it might not be possible to change the base class. If the base class already implements an interface, that's not an issue. So let's assume that it doesn't, like in your code.

To implement decorator in this case, we first need to create an [adapter](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) for our base class and implement our decorator alongside it.

So let's assume the base class is `Computer` and that we can't change it:

```
public sealed class Computer
{
    public string getComputer()
    {
        return "computer";
    }
}
```

To create an adapter, we create the `IComputer` interface like before, and a class that wraps `Computer`:

```
public sealed class ComputerAdapter : IComputer
{
    private Computer _computer;
    public ComputerAdapter(Computer computer)
    {
        _computer = computer;
    }

    public string getComputer()
    {
        return _computer.getComputer();
    }
}
```

The decorators remain unchanged from the previous example, since they already implement `IComputer`. Wrapping it up changes a little, since we now have to pass a `Computer` to our `ComputerAdapter` instance:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Computer sealedComputer = new Computer();
        IComputer computer = new KeyBoard(new Monitor(new Disk(new ComputerAdapter(sealedComputer))));

        Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
    }
}
```

But the result is the same, as can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/hURpWf).

## Why does your code work in Java, but not in C#?

While it doesn't actually implement decorator, your code would work if `Computer.getComputer()` was `virtual`. In your code, in `Main`, `computer` is of type `Computer`. Since `getComputer()` is not `virtual`, `Computer.getComputer()` is called instead of the intended `KeyBoard.getComputer()`. Since in Java every method is always `virtual`, that problem doesn't happen.

Your C# compiler should be giving you a warning that `getComputer()` from subclasses is hiding the original implementation. Warnings indicate that what you're doing will compile, but might not do what you expect, which is the case here.

Answer (score 3):

`computer.getComputer()` in following line

```
Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
```

calls Computer's version of `getComputer` because it is the compile time type(as method is not virtual).

If you need polymorphic behavior, you need to mark `getComputer` in computer class as `virtual`. You could then completely remove that `ComponentDecorator` class which adds nothing.

> Why is this happens C# only not in Java?

Because by default all methods are virtual(can be overridden) in java. In c# it is not. You need to explicitly mark it `virtual`.

So your complete implementation becomes

```
public class Computer
{
    public Computer()
    {
    }

    public virtual String getComputer()
    {
        return "computer";
    }
}

public class Disk : Computer
{
    Computer computer;
    public Disk(Computer c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }


    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a disk";
    }

}

public class Monitor : Computer
{
    Computer computer;
    public Monitor(Computer c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }
    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a Monitor";
    }
}

public class KeyBoard : Computer
{
    Computer computer;
    public KeyBoard(Computer c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }

    public override String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a KeyBoard";
    }

    public string call()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: He's asking about the decorator pattern. The idea is to decorate the `Computer` class without modifying it's code.

Comment: @InBetween I know. It has to be virtual in [decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern). Otherwise OP needs to use field type as `ComputerDecorator` not `Computer`.

Comment: @InBetween Also note OP's question is why this isn't happening in java? Because all methods are overridable in java by default. So when converting that code to c# he **must** add virtual

Comment: The key is to introduce an interface `IComputer`. It defines the method `getComputer()`. `Computer` can implement the interface without  `getComputer()` having to be virtual, as can the decorators.

Comment: @BartvanNierop Yes, that will do. But how that doesn't violates decorator pattern (without modifying the `Computer` class) ?

Comment: Obviously he can modify `Computer`, since he wrote it, therefore `Computer` can implement `IComputer`. If you can't modify it, you can't make `getComputer()` virtual, either.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel When I made my comment you hadn't edited the answer including why it works in java and not in C#. You were simply stating that the solution was to make the method virtual which is not a precise answer as that may not be always possible. Your answer now is 100% accurate and spot on although  I'd add that if the method is not virtual and you have no way to make it virtual then you can not apply the decorator pattern. ;) upvoted.

Comment: At first glance I missed that java part. That's why it wasn't in my initial part. Also I have a practice that I'll add a small answer with little information and continuously I update my answer to provide more info :)

Comment: @BartvanNierop: Well I'm pretty sure most code posted on SO is simplified scenarios and not production code. The fact remains that using the decorator pattern to decorate classes that you don't own or have the code of is a normal scenario. So making something virtual is not always an option. It's more precise to say that in order to use the decorator pattern the way the OP is pretending to the method *must* be virtual.

Comment: @Inbetween Or you could add an adapter.

Comment: @InBetween If you can't make it `virtual`,  you'll need to use combination of Adapter and Decorator pattern. i.e you define your own adapter interface and expose it to client. Client code will depend on Adapter rather than the component itself. Then you add number of decorators

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Of course, but then its not the intended use of the pattern as shown in the code posted by the OP.

Comment: Doesn't really look like the link you posted http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern This is just the `Component` and then some concrete decorators. There's no `ConcreteComponent` If you had a `ConcreteComputer` then `Computer` could be abstract or an interface, then the virtual discussion is moot.

Answer (score 0):

The `Computer.getComputer` method is not marked as `virtual`, and the `ComponentDecorator.getComputer` method is not marked as `override`. In C# you can create a method in a derived class with the same signature as a method in the base class without getting a compiler error (although you will get a warning). The effect of this is is that the method in the derived class "hides" the method in the base class rather than overriding it, so if you call the method through a reference typed as the derived class you get the derived class's implementation, but if you call the method through a reference typed as the base class you get the base class implementation. For example:

```
void Main()
{
    DerivedHide d1 = new DerivedHide();
    Console.WriteLine(d1.GetName()); // "DerivedHide"
    Base b = d1;
    Console.WriteLine(b.GetName());  // "Base"

    DerivedOverride d2 = new DerivedOverride();
    Console.WriteLine(d2.GetName());// "DerivedOverride"
    b = d2;
    Console.WriteLine(b.GetName()); // "DerivedOverride"
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual string GetName(){ return "Base"; }
}

public class DerivedHide : Base
{
    public string GetName() { return "DerivedHide"; } // causes compiler warning
}

public class DerivedOverride : Base
{
    public override string GetName() { return "DerivedOverride"; }
}
```

If you add `virtual` to `Computer.getComputer` and `override` to `ComponentDecorator.getComputer` your code will work as expected.

(BTW, the convention in C# (unlike Java) is to write method names in PascalCase rather than camelCase, so `Computer.GetComputer` would be preferred to `Computer.getComputer`.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Decorator Pattern as in your example you need `Computer.GetComputer()` to be virtual. In Java I think all methods are virtual by default. That is not the case in C# where you explicitly need to define the method as virtual through the `virtual` keyword. That is why the code works in java but not in C#.

Still that is not the only issue in your code. Even if you make `Computer.GetComputer()` virtual, the output remains the same. The other issue is that you hare effectively hiding the base class `Computer.GetComputer()` method in your `ComponentDecorator` (the C# compiler allows you to elide the `new` keyword although it will give you a warning). To keep the method virtual, you need to define the method as `public abstract override String getComputer();`. Although it may seem strange, `abstract override` is perfectly valid in C#: [What is the use of 'abstract override' in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905432/what-is-the-use-of-abstract-override-in-c/8906233#8906233) Again this works in Java because `ComponentDecorator.GetComputer` is also virtual by default.

With those two changes your code will work well enough although I agree with other answers in that you are better off just subclassing `Computer` directly instead of using the `DecoratorComponent`. If `Computer` is not in your codebase and the method`GetComputer` is not virtual then you will have to use a different pattern.

Comment: public abstract override String getComputer(); is the solution to my problem. Because I want to decorate Computer, so it should be unchanged, even in my case (real application I am working with now) it is not possible to change anything in Computer class.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with something like this, if I were to implement the decorator pattern -

```
public interface IComponent
{
    String getComputer();
}
public class Computer : IComponent
{
    public Computer()
    {
    }

    public virtual String getComputer()
    {
        return "computer";
    }
}

public interface IComponentDecorator : IComponent
{
}

public class Disk : IComponentDecorator
{
    IComponent computer;
    public Disk(IComponent c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }


    public String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a disk";
    }

}

public class Monitor : IComponentDecorator
{
    IComponent computer;
    public Monitor(IComponent c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }
    public String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a Monitor";
    }

}

public class KeyBoard : IComponentDecorator
{
    IComponent computer;
    public KeyBoard(IComponent c)
    {
        computer = c;
    }

    public String getComputer()
    {
        return computer.getComputer() + " and a KeyBoard";
    }

    public string call()
    {
        return "";
    }

}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComponent computer = new Computer();
        computer = new Disk(computer);
        computer = new Monitor(computer);
        computer = new KeyBoard(computer);


        Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

The output? -

```
You are getting a computer and a disk and a Monitor and a KeyBoard
```

[image]

And here is some more samples - [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: Why would you make `Computer` implement `ComponentDecorator`? Isn't `Computer` the type being decorated, not the decorator? It would make more sense if the other types implemented `ComponentDecorator` *instead of* deriving from `Computer`.

Comment: @SteveRuble, yeah, the previous code was wrong, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the code examples here actually implement the decorator pattern (well, they didn't when I wrote this...). It defeats the point if the concrete classes and decorators are part of the same inheritance tree. In that case there would be no point to actually store a reference to a concrete object, because you could simply call `base`.

In the decorator pattern, your concrete classes and decorators should implement a common interface. It doesn't rely on inheritance nor polymorphism.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    String getComputer();
}

public class Computer : IComponent
{
    public String getComputer()
    {
        return "computer";
    }
}

public abstract class ComponentDecorator
{
    protected ComponentDecorator(IComponent component)
    {
        this.Component = component;
    }

    protected IComponent Component { get; private set; }
}

public class Disk : ComponentDecorator, IComponent
{
    public Disk(IComponent c) : base(c)
    {
    }

    public String getComputer()
    {
        return this.Component.getComputer() + " and a disk";
    }
}

public class Monitor : ComponentDecorator, IComponent
{
    public Monitor(IComponent c)
        : base(c)
    {
    }

    public String getComputer()
    {
        return this.Component.getComputer() + " and a monitor";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComponent computer = new Monitor(new Disk(new Computer()));

        Console.WriteLine(" You are getting a " + computer.getComputer());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I extracted an interface. You could use an abstract class all the same, though. The abstract decorator is simply to re-use storing the component reference, but nothing more.

The point is that the decorators shouldn't inherit from the concrete class(es), because that would defeat the point of the decorator pattern. As you can see, I didn't even make the base decorator implement the interface to demonstrate that you need absolutely no late binding.

BTW: `getComputer()` violates the C# conventions. It should be a property in C# and start with a capital letter. Apart from language-specific conventions, the name of the method is lying about its intention.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution to my problem will be

```
public abstract override String getComputer()
```

in `ComponentDecorator` which is suggested by InBetween; Because I want to decorate Computer, so it should be unchanged, even in my case (real application I am working with now) it is not possible to change anything in Computer class.

Comment: That might be the solution that makes your code work with the least amount of change, but it doesn't actually implement decorator. Decorators exist _next to_ the component they decorate. They don't inherit it.