# Inherit abstract class inside another abstract class with same function names

Tags: c#

I have two abstract classes `AbstractClass1` and `AbstractClass2` that both should have the same method names `Meth1`.

Now what if my `AbstractClass1` inherits from `AbstractClass2`. Currently it is throwing me a compile time error as  `"Hides Inherited Abstract Member"`. Below is my code.

```
 abstract class AbstractClass1 : AbstractClass2
 {
    public abstract string Meth1();
 }

 abstract class AbstractClass2
 {
    public abstract string Meth1();
 }
```

Comment: as both methods are abstract there is **no** reason to give a `new` declaration in your `AbstractClass1` at all - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: If `AbstractClass1` extends `AbstractClass2`, why do you need to declare the method again?

Comment: you cab override the Meth1() in AbstractClass1.But why you need such kind of a declaration?

Comment: why do you need this ?

Comment: Hi, Its not a real time scenario Carsten, Glorfindel, Joseph and Farid. I was just doing it for my R and D as it was asked me in my recent interviews. Thanks a lot for your replies :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `abstract override` on derived class method to avoid compile time error.

```
abstract class BaseAbstract
{
    public abstract string Meth1();
}

abstract class ChildAbstract : BaseAbstract
{
    public abstract override string Meth1();
}
```

**BUT** **please note that** this is not quite right place to use `abstract override`.
Usually abstract override is used when deriving an abstract class from non abstract class. to ensure that derived class implements the method. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905432/what-is-the-use-of-abstract-override-in-c))

Take a look at below code

```
class BaseNonAbstract
{
      public virtual string Meth1()
      {
         // do something
         return string.Empty;
      }
}
abstract class ChildAbstract : BaseNonAbstract
{
    public abstract override string Meth1();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
abstract class AbstractClass1 : AbstractClass2
{
}


abstract class AbstractClass2
{
    public abstract string Meth1();
}
```