# Set as abstract an abstract function C#

Tags: c#, class, overriding, abstract

Can I set as abstract an abstract function? Can I do this:

```
public abstract class A
{
   protected abstract void WhateverFunction();
}

public abstract class B:A
{
   protected abstract void WhateverFunction();
}

public abstract class C:B
{
   protected override void WhateverFunction()
   {
      //code here
   }
}
```

If not, what can I do to simulate this behaviour?

Comment: What behavior are you talking about? Not compiling? That's easy enough. If you do want the code to compile, just omit the offending declaration of `WhateverFunction()` in `B`.

Comment: What should be WhateverFunction declaration in class B for?

Comment: maybe you [wanted this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8905465/1132334) instead?

Comment: Maybe you wanted this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/07/strange-but-legal/

Comment: "Can I do this?" questions can be answered by trying it. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you need to add the `override` modifier to the function declared on the `B` class. So, in this case, `WhateverFunction` is abstract and at the same time overrides the function on `A`:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract void WhateverFunction();
}

public abstract class B : A 
{
    protected abstract override void WhateverFunction(); // HERE
}

public abstract class C : B
{
    protected override void WhateverFunction()
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

In this case, you could also simply omit `WhateverFunction` on class B to achieve the same result.