# When override an abstract method, is it correct that I set abstract again?

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class, abstract

Maybe the title is confusing.

Let me put you an example:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class BaseA : Base
{
    protected abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class ClassA1 : BaseA
{
    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something!
    }
}

public class ClassA2 : BaseA
{
    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something!
    }
}
```

With this code, it's a similiar scenario from my real project. I have a base class. But I realized that base class needs to be abstract again, so the method DoSomething needs to be abstract again and I want to override it when I have the concrete class.

Is a good practice? Or are there a problem because I've set the method to abstract two times?

Comment: See also [An abstract method overrides an abstract method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768977/an-abstract-method-overrides-an-abstract-method), an older thread here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to declare the method on `BaseA`; all its subclasses will inherit it through its parent.

An `abstract override` [is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905432/what-is-the-use-of-abstract-override-in-c) when you want to redefine a concrete method as abstract on a subclass.

Comment: Oh that's right! I haven't noticed about that! Thanks a million!